# LAGEOS 1's time capsule's positioning in the sattelite

Tags: artificial-satellite

LAGEOS 1 is one of the two LAGEOS (LAzer GEOdynamics Sattelite) sattelites designed to study the movement of continents with minute precision using reflected light from hundreds of reflectors on its surface...

But that is not what I want to focus on. LAGEOS 1 contains a plaque, in part designed by Carl Sagan. The plaque is one of the many artifacts that are manmade designed to be "proofs" of our existence for future generations, or perhaps future civilizations or even aliens if they ever come in contact with one of those (the Pioneer plaque, the Golden Record etc.).

This is how it looks like if you don't know:

[image: LAGEOS plaque]

More info about the plaque: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAGEOS#Time_capsule

I was trying to find any more information about the plaque other than what it represents but I didn't find by myself any other valuable info. What info exactly?

I would like to know how the plaque is positioned inside the satellite. That is in which compartment it is placed and how it is placed inside (I assume inside since LAGEOS 1 is spherical while the plaque is mostly likely a flat plane).

Can anyone of you provide me with the position of the plaque inside LAGEOS 1?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article](https://theconversation.com/space-bling-jewelled-lageos-satellites-help-us-to-measure-the-earth-76948):

> The maps are engraved on a thin steel plate that was wrapped around the brass cylinder core.  You’d have to crack the satellite open like an egg, though, to get at the message.

Oh, and welcome to *Space!*

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @DrSheldon's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32086/12102), a video had been posted a few years ago by [NASA's Marshall Center](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYKfAzPEXMQsGtNfBCNa_BA). You can see how the cylindrical core mass is positioned in the spacecraft.

So far I haven't found an image of how the plaque was incorporated with the cylinder.  However, the [NASA Press Kit, RELEASE NO: 76-67](https://historydms.hq.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/DMS/e000045273.pdf) released at the time says:

> MESSAGE TO THE FUTURE
>
> A message has been sealed inside Lageos in the event it should be retrieved from crbit or discovered after its return to Earth some 10 million years from now.
>
> The message was prepared by Dr. Carl Sagan of the Laboratory for Planetary Studies at Cornell University, Ithaca, N.Y. Two copies of the message, **which is etched on
> stainless steel sheets measuring 10 by 18 cm (4 by 7 in.), are installed in the satellite -- one at each end of the bolt connecting the two hemispheres** which make up Lageos.

One end of the bolt can be see in this image from the press kit:

[image]

This is a clone of my answer to [Will LAGEOS burn up or be destroyed on impact?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15340/12102)

A few screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]