# Could solar sails be used in station keeping?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, station-keeping, passive-systems

Could solar sails work in place of solar vanes for passive stabilization in station keeping a satellite fixed in the Lagrange 2 point on a parallel orbit with the Moon?

Related:

[What is the principle behind Mariner 4's "Solar Pressure Vanes"? In what case(s) would they be effective?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27124/what-is-the-principle-behind-mariner-4s-solar-pressure-vanes-in-what-cases)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction between a solar sail and a solar vane, but that might just be me.

Answer (score 1):

Mariner 4's vanes articulate only to correct for unbalanced solar pressure, to help *maintain* attitude.  To receive enough solar pressure to navigate, i.e. *change* attitude and (even harder) change course, you'd need something much larger.  But even a big sail can only push you away from the sun -- more when facing it, less when sideways to it -- so a course correction might have to wait a few weeks until the moon is at the correct position in its orbit so the pressure is in the right direction in the earth-moon frame of reference.  While you're waiting for that, you might deviate too far from your halo orbit.

**Edit:** @uhoh's comment is correct. Tilting the sail *can* accelerate you sunward albeit slowly.  But maybe still too slow to stay in your halo orbit.

Comment: Tilting the sail relative to the Sun gives a lot of flexibility. If you reflect the light prograde or retrograde you produce retro/pro thrust to slow or speed up your orbit and change its size. If you point out-of-plane you can change your inclination. You can always move towards the Sun using a solar sail, but it's certainly slow. e.g.  [What is the functional form for r(t) for a solar-sail deorbit into the Sun?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30275/12102) and also [Is it possible to reach the Sun without expending any fuel/reaction mass?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30272/12102)

Answer (score 1):

A vane in this context is just an (articulated) panel used to alter the centre of pressure and effective orientation of the reflector. They are solar sails.

If you mean could these be entirely passive and still work: then no, not entirely. Some active control is required for station keeping. That said, the control doesn't have to be in moving the panel. Altering the reflective properties of the reflectors, of moving the centre of mass are also possible.