# What is the fastest that ParkinsonSat spun? Did it vary with solar activity?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, attitude-determination-and-control, rotation, amateur-radio, spin-stabilisation

[Why would photon pressure be needed to keep ParkinsonSAT Spinning?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44272/12102) explains that it was equipped with surfaces that resulted in a sunlight-induced torque which have

> ...succeeded in keeping the satellite spinning at a rate of several RPM for years.

and [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49908/12102) is thorough and suggests that the drag torque would counter the solar photon pressure induced torque at 80 RPM.

This would of course vary dramatically with solar activity; in LEO atmospheric density can vary of order a factor of ten or more, depending on altitude.

**Question:** What's the fastest that ParkinsonSat spun? Did it vary with solar activity? It's an amateur radio satellite named `Naval Academy OSCAR 84` so presumably had basic telemetry and a lot of people listening to it, was the rotation rate available, and if so is there record of it?